# LSALogonUser fails to authenticate domain users using AD issued certificates

Tags: c++, active-directory, windows-authentication, client-certificates, credential-providers

I am working on a certificate-based authentication project for domain users against Active Directory without the use of smartcards. I am trying to access the issued domain user certificate container and pass the value in a serialized format to LsaLogonUser for authentication.

First, I am enrolling the domain user certificate by creating a new certificate template described below:-

1. Duplicate a new certificate template from "User" certificate template.
2. In the **Properties of new certificate template** window, go to the **General** tab and change the following settings:

   - Check the "Publish certificate in Active Directory" box and enter a template name.
3. Go to the **Request Handling** tab and change the following settings:

   - Change "Purpose" to "Signature and encryption".
   - Check the box "Allow private key to be exported".
   - Select "Prompt the user during enrollment".
4. Go to the **Subject Name** tab and change the following settings:

   - Select "Build from this Active Directory information".
   - Change "Subject name format" to "None".
   - Check the "User principal name (UPN)" box.
5. Go to the **Extensions** tab and edit "Application Policies" so that the only listed policies are "Client Authentication" and "Smart Card Logon". (Remove any default policies as necessary.)
6. Go to the **Cryptography** tab and change the following settings:

   - Change "Minimum key size" to 2048.
   - Select "Requests must use one of the following providers: "
   - Select "Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0" as "Providers".

After making the above changes, issue/publish the new certificate template in Active Directory Certificate Authority.

The domain user enrolls using the new certificate template and the user certificate is stored in the current user's Certificate Store.

After the enrollment process is complete, I am trying to access the CSP container handle of the user certificate and using it for [KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntsecapi/ns-ntsecapi-kerb_certificate_logon) structure for packing and serializing the authentication data specified by [LsaLogonUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntsecapi/nf-ntsecapi-lsalogonuser). Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Ntsecapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <intsafe.h>
#include <WinCred.h>
#include <winbase.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Crypt32")

#define NEGOSSP_NAME_A  "Negotiate"


#ifndef STATUS_SUCCESS
#define STATUS_SUCCESS  ((NTSTATUS)0x00000000L)
#endif
#include <vcruntime_exception.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Secur32.lib")

using namespace std;

// 1-Byte packing for this structure
#pragma pack(push, KerbCspInfo, 1)
typedef struct _KERB_SMARTCARD_CSP_INFO {
    DWORD dwCspInfoLen;
    DWORD MessageType;
    union {
        PVOID   ContextInformation;
        ULONG64 SpaceHolderForWow64;
    };
    DWORD flags;
    DWORD KeySpec;
    ULONG nCardNameOffset;
    ULONG nReaderNameOffset;
    ULONG nContainerNameOffset;
    ULONG nCSPNameOffset;
    TCHAR bBuffer[sizeof(DWORD)];
} KERB_SMARTCARD_CSP_INFO, * PKERB_SMARTCARD_CSP_INFO;
#pragma pack(pop, KerbCspInfo)



HRESULT UnicodeStringInitWithString(
    _In_ PWSTR pwz,
    _Out_ UNICODE_STRING* pus
)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    if (pwz)
    {
        size_t lenString = wcslen(pwz);
        USHORT usCharCount;
        hr = SizeTToUShort(lenString, &usCharCount);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            USHORT usSize;
            hr = SizeTToUShort(sizeof(wchar_t), &usSize);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                hr = UShortMult(usCharCount, usSize, &(pus->Length)); // Explicitly NOT including NULL terminator
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    pus->MaximumLength = pus->Length;
                    pus->Buffer = pwz;
                    hr = S_OK;
                }
                else
                {
                    hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_ARITHMETIC_OVERFLOW);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        hr = E_INVALIDARG;
    }
    return hr;
}

static void _UnicodeStringPackedUnicodeStringCopy(
    __in const UNICODE_STRING& rus,
    __in PWSTR pwzBuffer,
    __out UNICODE_STRING* pus
)
{
    pus->Length = rus.Length;
    pus->MaximumLength = rus.Length;
    pus->Buffer = pwzBuffer;

    std::CopyMemory(pus->Buffer, rus.Buffer, pus->Length);
}

// Set the SeTcbPrivilege of the current process
BOOL SetSeTcbPrivilege()
{
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
    LUID luid;
    HANDLE hProcessToken;
    int x;

    if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(),
        TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES,
        &hProcessToken))
    {
        _tprintf(_T("OpenProcessToken failed with error 0x%.8X\n"), GetLastError());
        cin >> x;
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(
        NULL,
        SE_TCB_NAME,
        &luid))
    {
        _tprintf(_T("LookupPrivilegeValue failed with error 0x%.8X\n"), GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(hProcessToken);
        cin >> x;
        return FALSE;
    }

    tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    // Enable the privilege
    if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(
        hProcessToken,
        FALSE,
        &tp,
        sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES),
        (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL,
        (PDWORD)NULL))
    {
        _tprintf(_T("AdjustTokenPrivileges failed with error 0x%.8X\n"), GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(hProcessToken);
        cin >> x;
        return FALSE;
    }


    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("The token does not have the privilege \"SeTcbPrivilege\". \n"));
        CloseHandle(hProcessToken);
        cin >> x;
        return FALSE;
    }

    CloseHandle(hProcessToken);


    return TRUE;
}

// Build the authentication data used by LsaLogonUser



BOOL ConstructAuthCertInfo(const KERB_CERTIFICATE_UNLOCK_LOGON& rkiulIn,LPBYTE* ppbAuthInfo, ULONG* pulAuthInfoLen)
{
    UNICODE_STRING DomainName;
    UNICODE_STRING UserName;
    UNICODE_STRING Password;
    NTSTATUS Status;
    ULONG_PTR Ptr;
    ULONG AuthInfoLength;
    wstring WProvName;
    DWORD ProvSize = 0;
    wstring containerName;
    DWORD contSize = 0;
    HCRYPTPROV hProv;
    DWORD dwKeySpec;

    // Fetching the certificate context from the certificate store  
    // and recieving the CSP handle for the user certificate
    HCERTSTORE      hStoreHandle = NULL;
    PCCERT_CONTEXT  pCertContext = NULL;
    LPCTSTR pszStoreName = _T("MY");
    CERT_CREDENTIAL_INFO certInfo;
    HCRYPTHASH hHash;
    BOOL bStatus;
    DWORD dwHashLen = CERT_HASH_LENGTH;
    LPWSTR szMarshaledCred = NULL;
    HANDLE hToken;

    hStoreHandle = CertOpenSystemStore(NULL, pszStoreName);

    if (hStoreHandle)
    {
        // Since my certificate store has only one user certificate, tring to retrieve PCERT_CONTEXT for it
        pCertContext = CertFindCertificateInStore(
            hStoreHandle,
            PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING | X509_ASN_ENCODING,
            0,
            CERT_FIND_ANY,
            NULL,
            NULL);

        if (pCertContext)
        {

            BOOL bFreeHandle;

            // acquire private key container to this certificate    
            if (CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey(pCertContext, CRYPT_ACQUIRE_ALLOW_NCRYPT_KEY_FLAG, NULL, &hProv, &dwKeySpec, &bFreeHandle))
            {
                cout << "The private key container handle is accessed.. "<<endl<<"The dwKeySpec Value is: "<<dwKeySpec<<endl;
            

                //Fetching the container name where the certificate is stored
                if (CryptGetProvParam(hProv, PP_CONTAINER, NULL, &contSize, 0))
                {
                    BYTE* contName = (BYTE*)malloc(contSize);
                    if (CryptGetProvParam(hProv, PP_CONTAINER, contName, &contSize, 0))
                    {
                        containerName = wstring(contName, contName + contSize);
                        wcout << "The container name is: " << containerName << endl;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << "Could not get the container name. Exiting.."<<endl;
                        return FALSE;

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Could not get the container size. Exiting.."<<endl;
                    return FALSE;

                }

                //Fetching the CSP name where the certificate is stored
                if (CryptGetProvParam(hProv, PP_NAME, NULL, &ProvSize, 0))
                {
                    BYTE* ProvName = (BYTE*)malloc(ProvSize);
                    if (CryptGetProvParam(hProv, PP_NAME, ProvName, &ProvSize, 0))
                    {
                        WProvName = wstring(ProvName, ProvName + ProvSize);
                        wcout << "The name of the CSP is: " << WProvName << endl;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << "The CSP name could not be retrieved. Exiting.." << endl;
                        return FALSE;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "The CSP name size could not be retrieved. Exiting.." << endl;
                    return FALSE;
                }

             }
            else
            {
                cout << "Could not get the Private Key Container handle. Exiting...";
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Could not find the user certificate in the Certificate store. Exiting.." << endl;
            return FALSE;
        }
    }


    
    // Creating and initializing a PKERB_SMARTCARD_CSP_INFO struct for passing as an argument to KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON struct
    // This struct stores information regarding the CSP and container of the user certs

    DWORD dwReaderLen = (DWORD)_tcslen(L"") + 1;
    DWORD dwCardLen = (DWORD)_tcslen(L"") + 1;
    DWORD dwProviderLen = (DWORD)_tcslen(WProvName.c_str()) + 1;
    DWORD dwContainerLen = (DWORD)_tcslen(containerName.c_str()) + 1;
    DWORD dwBufferSize = dwReaderLen + dwCardLen + dwProviderLen + dwContainerLen;

    PKERB_SMARTCARD_CSP_INFO CspInfo = (PKERB_SMARTCARD_CSP_INFO)malloc(sizeof(KERB_SMARTCARD_CSP_INFO) + dwBufferSize * sizeof(TCHAR));
    std::memset(CspInfo, 0, sizeof(KERB_SMARTCARD_CSP_INFO));
    CspInfo->dwCspInfoLen = sizeof(KERB_SMARTCARD_CSP_INFO) + dwBufferSize * sizeof(TCHAR);
    CspInfo->MessageType = 1;
    CspInfo->KeySpec = dwKeySpec;
    CspInfo->nCardNameOffset = ARRAYSIZE(CspInfo->bBuffer);
    CspInfo->nReaderNameOffset = CspInfo->nCardNameOffset + dwCardLen;
    CspInfo->nContainerNameOffset = CspInfo->nReaderNameOffset + dwReaderLen;
    CspInfo->nCSPNameOffset = CspInfo->nContainerNameOffset + dwContainerLen;
    std::memset(CspInfo->bBuffer, 0, sizeof(CspInfo->bBuffer));
    _tcscpy_s(&CspInfo->bBuffer[CspInfo->nCardNameOffset], dwBufferSize + 4 - CspInfo->nCardNameOffset, L"");
    _tcscpy_s(&CspInfo->bBuffer[CspInfo->nReaderNameOffset], dwBufferSize + 4 - CspInfo->nReaderNameOffset, L"");
    _tcscpy_s(&CspInfo->bBuffer[CspInfo->nContainerNameOffset], dwBufferSize + 4 - CspInfo->nContainerNameOffset, containerName.c_str());
    _tcscpy_s(&CspInfo->bBuffer[CspInfo->nCSPNameOffset], dwBufferSize + 4 - CspInfo->nCSPNameOffset, WProvName.c_str());




    
    const KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON* pkilIn = &rkiulIn.Logon;

    // alloc space for struct plus extra for the three strings
    DWORD cb = sizeof(rkiulIn) +
        pkilIn->DomainName.Length +
        pkilIn->UserName.Length +
        pkilIn->Pin.Length +
        CspInfo->dwCspInfoLen;

    KERB_CERTIFICATE_UNLOCK_LOGON* pkiulOut = (KERB_CERTIFICATE_UNLOCK_LOGON*)CoTaskMemAlloc(cb);

    if (pkiulOut)
    {
        std::ZeroMemory(&pkiulOut->LogonId, sizeof(LUID));

        //
        // point pbBuffer at the beginning of the extra space
        //
        BYTE* pbBuffer = (BYTE*)pkiulOut + sizeof(*pkiulOut);

        //
        // set up the Logon structure within the KERB_CERTIFICATE_UNLOCK_LOGON
        //
        KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON* pkilOut = &pkiulOut->Logon;

        pkilOut->MessageType = pkilIn->MessageType;
        pkilOut->Flags = pkilIn->Flags;

        //
        // copy each string,
        // fix up appropriate buffer pointer to be offset,
        // advance buffer pointer over copied characters in extra space
        //
        _UnicodeStringPackedUnicodeStringCopy(pkilIn->DomainName, (PWSTR)pbBuffer, &pkilOut->DomainName);
        pkilOut->DomainName.Buffer = (PWSTR)(pbBuffer - (BYTE*)pkiulOut);
        pbBuffer += pkilOut->DomainName.Length;

        _UnicodeStringPackedUnicodeStringCopy(pkilIn->UserName, (PWSTR)pbBuffer, &pkilOut->UserName);
        pkilOut->UserName.Buffer = (PWSTR)(pbBuffer - (BYTE*)pkiulOut);
        pbBuffer += pkilOut->UserName.Length;

        _UnicodeStringPackedUnicodeStringCopy(pkilIn->Pin, (PWSTR)pbBuffer, &pkilOut->Pin);
        pkilOut->Pin.Buffer = (PWSTR)(pbBuffer - (BYTE*)pkiulOut);
        pbBuffer += pkilOut->Pin.Length;

        pkilOut->CspData = (PUCHAR)(pbBuffer - (BYTE*)pkiulOut);
        pkilOut->CspDataLength = CspInfo->dwCspInfoLen;

        std::memcpy(pbBuffer,CspInfo, CspInfo->dwCspInfoLen);




        *ppbAuthInfo = (BYTE*)pkilOut;
        *pulAuthInfoLen = cb;
        
        return TRUE;
    }
}
  


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    NTSTATUS nStatus;
    CHAR szProcName[] = "LsaTestLogonProcess";
    CHAR szPackageName[] = NEGOSSP_NAME_A;
    CHAR szOriginName[] = "LsaSmartCardLogonTest";
    LSA_STRING lsaProcName = { strlen(szProcName), strlen(szProcName) + 1, szProcName };
    LSA_STRING lsaPackageName = { strlen(szPackageName), strlen(szPackageName) + 1, szPackageName };
    LSA_STRING lsaOriginName = { strlen(szOriginName), strlen(szOriginName) + 1, szOriginName };
    HANDLE lsaHandle;
    ULONG ulAuthPackage;
    LPBYTE pbAuthInfo = NULL;
    ULONG  ulAuthInfoLen = 0;
    LSA_OPERATIONAL_MODE dummy;
    TOKEN_SOURCE tokenSource;
    LPVOID pProfileBuffer = NULL;
    ULONG ulProfileBufferLen = 0;
    LUID logonId;
    HANDLE hLogonToken;
    QUOTA_LIMITS quotas;
    NTSTATUS subStatus;
    HANDLE hToken = NULL;



    int x;
    wchar_t doman[] = L"TECNICS";
    wchar_t usernme[] = L"";
    wchar_t pn[] = L"";
    PWSTR domain = doman;
    PWSTR username = usernme;
    PWSTR pin = pn;


    //Certificate Based Auth
    KERB_CERTIFICATE_UNLOCK_LOGON ckiul;
    KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON* ckil = &ckiul.Logon;

    ckil->MessageType = KerbCertificateLogon;
    ckil->Flags = 2;

    // Converting Domain Name to Unicode Format
    UnicodeStringInitWithString(domain, &ckil->DomainName);

    // Passing empty UserName as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntsecapi/ns-ntsecapi-kerb_certificate_logon
    UnicodeStringInitWithString(username, &ckil->UserName);

    // Passing empty PIN since no PIN asked during enrollment
    UnicodeStringInitWithString(pin, &ckil->Pin);
    //End




    if (!SetSeTcbPrivilege())
    {
        cin >> x;
        return 0;
    }

 
    std::memcpy(tokenSource.SourceName, "LsaTest", 8);
    AllocateLocallyUniqueId(&tokenSource.SourceIdentifier);

    nStatus = LsaRegisterLogonProcess(&lsaProcName,
        &lsaHandle,
        &dummy);
    if (nStatus == STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        nStatus = LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage(lsaHandle,
            &lsaPackageName,
            &ulAuthPackage);
        if (nStatus == STATUS_SUCCESS)
        {

            if (!ConstructAuthCertInfo(ckiul, &pbAuthInfo, &ulAuthInfoLen))
            {
                cout << "Could not serialize the authentication data. Exiting...";
                cin >> x;
                return 0;
            }

            nStatus = LsaLogonUser(lsaHandle,
                &lsaOriginName,
                Interactive,
                ulAuthPackage,
                pbAuthInfo,
                ulAuthInfoLen,
                NULL,
                &tokenSource,
                &pProfileBuffer,
                &ulProfileBufferLen,
                &logonId,
                &hLogonToken,
                &quotas,
                &subStatus);
            if (nStatus == STATUS_SUCCESS)
            {
                if (pProfileBuffer)
                    LsaFreeReturnBuffer(pProfileBuffer);

                _tprintf(_T("User logged on successfully!!\n"));
                cin >> x;
                CloseHandle(hLogonToken);
            }
            else
            {
                _tprintf(_T("LsaLogonUser failed with error 0x%.8X. SubStatus = 0x%.8X\n"), LsaNtStatusToWinError(nStatus), LsaNtStatusToWinError(subStatus));
                cin >> x;
            }


            HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pbAuthInfo);
        }
        else
        {
            _tprintf(_T("LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage failed with error 0x%.8X\n"), LsaNtStatusToWinError(nStatus));
            cin >> x;
        }

        LsaDeregisterLogonProcess(lsaHandle);
    }
    else
    {
        _tprintf(_T("LsaRegisterLogonProcess failed with error 0x%.8X\n"), LsaNtStatusToWinError(nStatus));
        cin >> x;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE:** The user needs to have SeTcbPriveledge and admin rights to run the program. You can refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/act-as-part-of-the-operating-system) to set the SeTcbPriveledge for the domain user.

After running the above code in the domain user's environment, LSALogonUser fails and I get the following status values:

```
- Status: 0x0000052E/ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE (The user name or password is incorrect.)
- SubStatus: 0x8009000d/NTE_NO_KEY (Key does not exist.)
```

I have also pushed a repo on Github which consists of the code in with Visual Studio extensions. You can clone the repo from [here](https://github.com/danish-syed/LSALogonUserSample).

Can someone suggest a better approach or hints to make this work?